# R: Sum cells across row of dataframe A if corresponding cell in dataframe B is equal to some value

Tags: r

Dataframe A:

```
Tree  Apple Orange  Pear
1     0     0       1
0     0     1       1
1     1     0       1
1     0     0       0
```

Dataframe B:

```
WK1   WK2   WK3   WK4
1     2     3     8
3     4     2     1
1     3     2     5
6     2     5     8
```

Both dataframe A and B have the same dimensions. What I am trying to do is to sum the cells across the rows in dataframe B only if the corresponding cell in dataframe A is equal to one.

The expected output is:

```
WK1   WK2   WK3   WK4   SUM
1     2     3     8     9
3     4     2     1     3
1     3     2     5     4
6     2     5     8     6
```

Since (row 1 column 1) and (row 1 column 4) of dataframe A are equal to one, then (row 1 column 1) and (row 1 column 4) of dataframe B are summed. The non-abbreviated form of dataframe A and B have over 883 columns and 12000 rows, so I cant write the name of each column.

Comment: The third element SUM should be greater than 4 because you have 1 in Tree, Apple, and Pear

Answer (score 1):

Since the `A` dataframe has 1/0 value and you can multiply `A` dataframe with `B` and calculate row-wise sum.

```
B$SUM <- rowSums(A * B)
B

#  WK1 WK2 WK3 WK4 SUM
#1   1   2   3   8   9
#2   3   4   2   1   3
#3   1   3   2   5   9
#4   6   2   5   8   6
```

If you can have values other than 0 and 1 in `A` you can compare `A` with 1 and then multiply.

```
B$SUM <- rowSums(+(A == 1) * B)
```

Answer (score -1):

An option is to multiply by the datasets so that 0's will remain 0 and 1 will be replaced by the value of second dataset and as there are `NA`, we can use `na.rm` in `rowSums`

```
df2$SUM <- rowSums((df1 == 1) * df2, na.rm = TRUE)
df2
#  WK1 WK2 WK3 WK4 SUM
#1   1   2   3   8   9
#2   3   4   2   1   3
#3   1   3   2   5   9
#4   6   2   5   8   6
```

---

Or another option is `Map/Reduce`

```
df2$SUM <- Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, df1, df2))
```

---

Or we can `replace` the elements in 'df2' where 'df1' is 0 to `NA` and use `rowSums` to create the 'SUM' column in `base R`

```
df2$SUM <- rowSums(replace(df2, df1 ==0, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or slightly more compact option is

```
df2$SUM <- rowSums(df2 *NA^(df1== 0), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

NOTE: This would also work when there are non-binary elements

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Tree = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Apple = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), Orange = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Pear = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(WK1 = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 6L), WK2 = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 2L
), WK3 = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 5L), WK4 = c(8L, 1L, 5L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```